# Historical Examples of Disagreements About Proofs

Tags: math-history

I'm looking for historical examples of theorems for which multiple proofs were proposed, where everyone agreed that all the proofs are correct, but where there was still substantial disagreement amongst mathematicians concerning the merits of the proofs, i.e. where mathematicians disagreed about which proof is simplest, or most illuminating, or most explanatory etc. References would be especially helpful.

Comment: You could look at the Brouwer-Hilbert controversy and the Hilbert Basis Theorem.

Comment: "which proof is simplest, or most illuminating, or most explanatory" is quite subjective, so different opinions between mathematicians are likely concerning this. Important is that there is a proof that can be followed (in the best case by every mathematician , but some proofs are so difficult that we must be content if sufficient many mathematicians can follow them)

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have in mind?